# Cocos3d:OpenGL error 0x0506 in -[EAGLView swapBuffers] and blank scene

Tags: cocos3d

In my cocos3d application, i have a UIViewController as rootview controller and from there i'll launch again Cocos3d scenes when use clicking on an option.

Here is my code below to launch scene from this view controller. Issue is, if i open uiviewcontroller and then move to scene by clicking on an option more than twice, then i'm getting error as "OpenGL error 0x0506 in -[EAGLView swapBuffers]
[***GL ERROR***] Unknown GL error (1286), before drawing HomeOwners3DScene Unnamed:1691. To investigate further, set the preprocessor macro GL_ERROR_TRACING_ENABLED=1 in your project build settings."

**[This issue doesn't come first time when i view the scene, it shows properly. But if i go back and click back to show the scene more than twice or more, then it appeared to be blank scene with the below error in xcode]**

Code below to move from my viewcontroller to further scenes:

```
    -(void) launchMainScene :(UIViewController *) uiViewCrtller
{
[uiViewCrtller.view removeFromSuperview];

// This must be the first thing we do and must be done before establishing view controller.
if( ! [CCDirector setDirectorType: kCCDirectorTypeDisplayLink] )
[CCDirector setDirectorType: kCCDirectorTypeDefault];

// Default texture format for PNG/BMP/TIFF/JPEG/GIF images.
// It can be RGBA8888, RGBA4444, RGB5_A1, RGB565. You can change anytime.
CCTexture2D.defaultAlphaPixelFormat = kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888;

// Create the view controller for the 3D view.
viewController = [CC3DeviceCameraOverlayUIViewController new];
//viewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;

// Create the CCDirector, set the frame rate, and attach the view.
CCDirector *director = CCDirector.sharedDirector;
//director.runLoopCommon = YES;  // Improves display link integration with UIKit
[director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
director.animationInterval = (1.0f / kAnimationFrameRate);
director.displayFPS = YES;
director.openGLView = viewController.view;

// Enables High Res mode on Retina Displays and maintains low res on all other devices
// This must be done after the GL view is assigned to the director!
[director enableRetinaDisplay: YES];

[director setDepthTest:NO];

// Create the window, make the controller (and its view) the root of the window, and present the window

[window addSubview: viewController.view];

CCDirector.sharedDirector.displayFPS = NO;

[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

// Set to YES for Augmented Reality 3D overlay on device camera.
// This must be done after the window is made visible!
viewController.isOverlayingDeviceCamera = NO;

// Create the customized CC3Layer that supports 3D rendering and schedule it for automatic updates.
CC3Layer* cc3Layer = [HomeOwners3DLayer node];
[cc3Layer scheduleUpdate];

// Create the customized 3D scene and attach it to the layer.
// Could also just create this inside the customer layer.
cc3Layer.cc3Scene = [HomeOwners3DScene scene];

// Assign to a generic variable so we can uncomment options below to play with the capabilities
CC3ControllableLayer* mainLayer = cc3Layer;

CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
[scene addChild: mainLayer];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: scene];

}
```

Below Error is throwing in Xcode console when i launch scene and go back viewcontroller and launch scene multiple times with showing blank screen in the scene:
****[This issue doesn't come first time when i view the scene, it shows properly. But if i go back and click back to show the scene more than twice or more, then it appeared to be blank scene with the below error in xcode]****
OpenGL error 0x0506 in -[EAGLView swapBuffers]
[***GL ERROR***] Unknown GL error (1286), before drawing HomeOwners3DScene Unnamed:1691. To investigate further, set the preprocessor macro GL_ERROR_TRACING_ENABLED=1 in your project build settings.

Please help to solve my problem.

Thank you.